# iso is already present on server

Tags: hyper-v, scvmm

I'm using SCVMM R2 with Windows 2008 R2 hosts.

I've noticed that if I have an iso mounted on a vm from the scvmm library and then a snapshot is restored then you always get an error

.iso is already present on server when trying add it again.

I know you can log onto the Host and delete the iso from the Virtual Machine foler but that will be a nigthmare in a 200 VM strong implimentation.

is there another way?

Comment: Why is the ISO in the VM dir and not in the SCVMM Library?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in VMM, have a look at this thread: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/virtualmachingmgrhyperv/thread/d5695d04-ebc7-4fec-8b27-6cb58848ee5f

Hope this will be helpful.